# Connecting MikroORM migration with Postgresql? npx command is failing. What am I missing?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, mikro-orm

I'm having a similar issue as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625224/mikro-orm-error-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres?newreg=36a19ba8482747daba5f1ad6cdf3effa).
Following Ben Awad's YouTube tutorial: [see here for where](https://youtu.be/I6ypD7qv3Z8?t=1927) I am in the tutorial.

**Goal**: Run `npx mikro-orm migration:create` to create a Mikro ORM migration as shown in the tutorial.

**What I did so far**: I was able to setup Postgres 13 and connect via the psql CLI (SQL Shell) and the pgAdmin tool. But when I run the `npx mikro-orm migration:create` in my VS Code terminal, I get:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\EJdesktop\Web Dev\playground\reddit-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:357:11)
        at Parser.handlePacket (C:\EJdesktop\Web Dev\playground\reddit-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:186:21)
        at Parser.parse (C:\EJdesktop\Web Dev\playground\reddit-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:101:30)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\EJdesktop\Web Dev\playground\reddit-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:307:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:282:9)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:221:10)
        at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
      length: 163,
      severity: 'FATAL',
      code: '28P01',
      detail: undefined,
      hint: undefined,
      position: undefined,
      internalPosition: undefined,
      internalQuery: undefined,
      where: undefined,
      schema: undefined,
      table: undefined,
      column: undefined,
      dataType: undefined,
      constraint: undefined,
      file: 'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\libpq\\auth.c',
      line: '336',
      routine: 'auth_failed'
    }
```

Here is my `mikro-orm.config.ts` file:

```
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import path from "path";


export default {
        migrations: {
            //join file paths
            path: path.join(__dirname, './migrations'), // path to the folder with migrations
            pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/, // regex pattern for the migration files
        },
        entities: [Post],
        dbName: 'postgres',
        type: 'postgresql',
        debug: !__prod__
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0]
```

My `pg_hba.conf` (for Postgres) originally showed as follows:

```
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Tried changing it to add 3 more lines to match the [example referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625224/mikro-orm-error-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres?newreg=36a19ba8482747daba5f1ad6cdf3effa):

```
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

I keep getting the same error.

Let me know if I can clarify anything further. Any advice?

Comment: i believe u r using linux

Answer (score 0):

1. In `pg_hba.conf` file change postgres user's method to md5. Keep the
   trusted ones as they are.
2. Go to `postgresql.conf` file. It's in the same directory as the
   `pg_hba.conf`. Change the default port to 5432. Mine was set to 5433
   for some reason.
3. Run this command: `sudo service postgresql restart`. Go to your
   config object and add `user` and `password` properties and indicate
   "postgres" as user, and whatever password you set for postgres user.
4. Now run `npx mikro-migration:create`.

Hopefully this will help.